# Hashset in Nim-lang

Tags: hashset, nim-lang

I am trying to use HashSet type of nim-lang but receiving error

```
var list = initSet\[int]()
```

and error is

```
Error: undeclared identifier: 'initSet'
```

I have already imported hashes library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in the [sets](http://nim-lang.org/docs/sets.html) module, not [hashes](http://nim-lang.org/docs/hashes.html).

```
import sets

proc sum(xs: HashSet[int]): int =
  for x in xs:
    result += x

var list = initHashSet[int]()
list.incl(10)
list.incl(20)
list.incl(30)

echo list.sum
```

Comment: feel moronic i was looking at imports section(bit of misleading) also is there a proc to sum the contents of the set

Comment: excellent did not knew we can write extension methods like this. thanks a lot

Comment: Note, that `initSet` is deprecated since v0.20, use 'initHashSet' instead.